# how to un encode url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urlencode

i need this address

localhost:2036/customers?linkTab=#tabs1-css

my code is:

```
 @Url.Action(MVC.Customers.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Customers.Name,
   new
   {    
   linkTab="#tabs1-css"
   })"
```

but my code generic this address

localhost:2036/customers?linkTab=%23tabs1-css

how to disable encode url in mvc?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want this? Your link will be broken.

Comment: in customers view i have a tab with address #tabs1-css

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a reserved character so you can't use it for other purposes without encoding it.
You can refer [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters):

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
>   special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
>   scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
>   purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded.

But if you want to use it as an anchor you can try this:

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Customers.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Customers.Name)#tabs1-css
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your solution (see @VahidND's answer for an explanation of the `#` character):

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Customers.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Customers.Name)#tabs1-css">MyLink</a>
```